# Load view depending user type logged

Tags: php, codeigniter

I´m actually using Codeigniter with php in my project and when a user is logged at the page if its a normal user load the same view if his a admin but changing some things in it.

I think that passing a variable to the controller and depending in it load the view with the  changes depending on the user.. but the url its seems not ver cool let se this:

```
        public function dc($q="")
    {
        if($q=="o")
        {

        // Here i have to change some parts of the template for normal users
        $this->load->view('Main/template_main', $data, FALSE);
        }elseif ($q=="a") {
            // Here i have to change some parts of the template for admins
        $this->load->view('Main/template_main', $data, FALSE);
```

The url is like www.xxx.com/controller/o or /a I want to see it like www.xxx.com/controller because its the index page..

Thanks for  your time..

Comment: I wouldn't decide on an url segment if the user is logged or not, you surely have some sessions setting that, right? Use that to decide which view load

Comment: The question title is different about what you're asking. Usually MVC frameworks doesn't work like this. There should be an indicator in the URL for showing what controller should get loaded. If you want to do that type of thing you can set it in `routes.php`. Like `$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/$1";`. And I still doubt about your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should approach this in the way that Damien suggests. Your controller should set session data something like:

```
$this->session->set_userinfo('is_admin', FALSE);
```

Then, when you have checked the login creds, you can set the session data when the user is an admin:

```
$this->session->set_userinfo('is_admin', TRUE);
```

On your page, you can then set who sees what based on this value.